# What does "APPS System has denied boarding for pax" mean?

Tags: australia, singapore, denied-boarding

I'm trying to check in on Scoot's website for a sydney-singapore flight but it keeps telling me "APPS System has denied boarding for pax". Does anyone have any idea what that means? I do not have phone access at the moment to ask Scoot.

Comment: Is it a direct flight?

Comment: It seems to mean something very bad. If that says the same thing when you are physically there then from the sound of it you may be denied boarding unless you have a Singapore passport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Denied boarding: Received ETA for Australia and have confirmation email, but it did not show up on their computer when checking in with airline!](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131199/denied-boarding-received-eta-for-australia-and-have-confirmation-email-but-it)

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That answer describes a system called "APP" which screens people entering Australia.  It's not clear how that would apply to someone exiting Australia.  "APPS" could refer to the same Australian system being used to screen people leaving, or a similarly-named system run by Singapore's immigration service, or something else entirely.  Unfortunately "APPS" is hard to Google...

Comment: @NateEldredge Oops, I misread the itinerary as Singapore-Sydney.

Comment: What is your nationality? Are you a dual national? Is this the first time you are using this passport to leave Australia?

Comment: Think it might be because I was trying to use an emergency passport's serial number to check in, and it probably was not in the system. I had to use my old passport's number to check in.

Answer (score 8):

We can't interpret a particular web site's error message. I will say that when you try to check in online and it fails, sometimes that's because you can't check in at all and other times it's not. For example, you might need to show someone that you have a visa or some other minor thing.I've been unable to check in because I had SSSS, and because I was selected for an upgrade. There might be nothing wrong.

The best thing to do is to go to the airport early. Check [their web page](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/fly-scoot/at-the-airport/checking-in) to see how early check in opens, and be there then. If it's possible to check you in, you're all set. And if not, you'll have a real life Scoot rep right there to help you figure out what to do next.