# What does it mean if you are "red flagged" at the airport even before you go through security?

Tags: airport-security

My story is very long and complicated and full of conspiracy theories as to what happened so I'm just going to keep it simple and just ask, how can a second time flyer get "red flagged" at the airport at the very front desk even before going through security?

Comment: do you mean SSSS? It can happen without any conspiracy theories at all eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6383/what-does-ssss-on-my-boarding-pass-mean/6386?r=SearchResults&s=1|49.2154#6386 or https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144570/what-does-apps-system-has-denied-boarding-for-pax-mean/144573?r=SearchResults&s=3|20.1697#144573

Comment: What do you mean more specifically, "red flagged" by whom? What country? What agency? An airline or government?

Comment: Who told you were “red flagged” (rather than just “flagged”)? What were the consequences? What country is this? Yo what destination?

Answer (score 8):

It is unclear what you mean with ‘red flagged’.
You seem to assume this is a standard term, but it is not - unless you mean an umpire literally throwing a red flag at your feet.

If you mean getting an ‘SSSSS’ written on your boarding pass - it is mostly *random selections*. I got two of them in about 300 flights over the last ten years - it doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: And note that an infrequent flyer very well might be more likely to draw a SSSS than a frequent flyer.  Frequent flyers have established a pattern of not doing bad things.